# Which password manager encrypts my passwords locally?

Tags: windows, gratis, password-manager

In light of all the recent hackings on the news, I no longer trust the cloud. Theoretically, if I use a cloud-based password manager (like LastPass or Dashlane), someone could hack into that service's database and would have access all of my saved login credentials.

I want to use a free password manager that will encrypt my passwords in a locally stored location; that way the only way that someone could have access to my passwords is to physically take my computer and and attempt to decrypt its contents.

Looks like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) offers that functionality (since it doesn't have any cloud functionality at all). Is there another one?

Comment: I assume you need this for Windows (as the official KeePass release is for Windows only), so I added it as a tag. If you need this for a different OS, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Speaking about the cloud sync option that most password managers use: yes they save a file in the cloud but this also is encrypted and the key usually is your main password (the one you need to use to open that kind of app to have access to all your passwords). So even if someone have access to this file they probably will not be able to decrypt it and won't be able to access your passwords.

Answer (score 4):

I've been a long time user of [Password Safe](https://pwsafe.org/) before switching to Lastpass. It was written by Bruce Schneier (I trust him implementing crypto correctly), [then made open source](https://www.schneier.com/passsafe.html).

While I used PWSafe, my wife used Keepass ;-) Both are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Enpass](https://www.enpass.io/security/) is my choice for password management. For me, cloud sync is a must have feature, but Enpass uses local encryption by default. Just don't set up cloud sync.