# Is there an offline password manager addon for Opera/Chrome/Firefox, with master password?

Tags: linux, offline, firefox, password-manager

The built-in Opera password manager has no master password :(

Search here with "password manager" and you will get 180+ results! :o
https://addons.opera.com/en/search/?query=password+manager

I tried all these addons but none worked, or I didn't manage to make them run or install properly, may be outdated or not Linux compatible?
[Which password manager encrypts my passwords locally?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/which-password-manager-encrypts-my-passwords-locally)

I will use a huge random password generator to create these non-rememberable passwords.

REQUIREMENTS:

1. So, the password manager MUST NOT send/backup my passwords to the cloud or any external site!!! (if I ever need to restore them, I just go to each site and try to recover the access using my email)
2. It also MUST have a master password, so in case someone robs my pc they would have to decrypt such local storage to get my passwords what would give me sometime to take action and change them all before that happens.

Obs.: later I will ask the same question about Chrome/Chromium and Firefox, I will just try to find something there, so if you know anything about these 2, that info will be welcome :).

PS.: I am on Ubuntu 20.04, but a browser addon should be platform independent I guess.

Answer (score 2):

For now I will be using `sudo apt install keepassx`.
It has a master password or key file!

But the opera's addon keepasshelper(https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/keepasshelper/) cant connect to it at localhost:19455, as keepassx seems to not run a server at all..

At least I can use keepassx to show the url on whatever browser I want, and it has an amazing window match + auto-type (user/password) feature! So this ends up being able to work with any browser!

keepassx just ends up not being integrated (no server nor related functional browser addon), therefore it is just a bit more complicated to use.

So, a better answer that provides an addon/extension that is integrated, preferably to more browsers than Opera, would be great!

Comment: Yes, that addon seems to need some keepass plugin, but no such plugins are available for keepassx.

Comment: Have you looked into [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/download/#linux) and [these instructions for the KeePassHelper addon](https://discuss.getsol.us/d/4658-making-keepassxc-work-in-opera-browser)?